# Converting lots of Word documents (.doc, docx, .odt) to pdf documents

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I already have a solution for this task:
I use the Word Interop classes, create n word instances and let them convert (save as) all my files. (Where n is the amount of threads which can be changed to reduce performance load or increase performance)
This works with the following speeds:
100 files -> 15,6 Sekunden
1.000 -> 156s = ~2 ½ Minuten
10.000 -> 1562s = 26 Minuten

As you can see it's rather slow...

What alternatives could I look into to speed up this process?
It can be in Java or C#.
It must have equal conversion accuracy compared to MS Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The faster approach I found for creating Word documents is using an XSLT stylesheet to transform the data from an XML source. I don't have time measurements, but it's much faster than COM Interop.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872374(v=office.12).aspx

http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/3798066/Take-the-Pain-out-of-Creating-Word-Documents-by-Using-C-and-XML.htm

Also, beware that using Office Automation is not a supported scenario for web sites or unattended applications.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: I am trying to convert existing word files to pdf files and we don't have the raw data in any reasonable format. I don't see how your links can help me with this. They seem to just deal with conversion of xml data to .doc(x) files.

Comment: Ok, I missed the PDF part. However, same solution applies if your  documents are in the new docx format. As you might known, those files are just a zip with another extension, and they content, among other, xml files with the document content. So, you could extract the content and convert them to PDF using XSLT-FO
See this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/595650/Creating-PDF-documents-from-XML